# cannot access return enumerable c# MVC Api

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, api, azure-sql-database

I have a c# MVC API that accessing stored procedures on Azure SQL and is working fine, including returning data to the APP that calls it.

As soon as I try and add any logic into the API to do anything with enumerable from SQL stops working when I try and use `First()` or `FirstOrDefault()`

This works and the app gets a nice list of records, in this case 1 record.

```
var r = objapi.storedProcudureName(arguments).AsEnumerable();
return r;
```

This fails

```
var r = objapi.storedProcudureName(arguments).AsEnumerable();
var r1 = r.First();
```

this also fails

```
var r = objapi.storedProcudureName(arguments).AsEnumerable();
var r1 = r.FirstOrDefault();
```

what am I missing here?

Comment: How is it failing? What errors are you getting?

Comment: Knowing what error you are seeing will help identify the correct solution. As Sajeetharan posted in his answer, it's likely you need to cast the enumeration into a concrete type first (such as a List<T>).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
var r1 = r.ToList().First();
```

Comment: thanks, I tried tolist also, but not with first.  That fixed it.

Comment: But a new interesting problem.  If I add that line of code it works, the api executes, but the APP never sees the return data.  Adding other lines of code between var r= and return r does not break it, but that line does all by itself.

Comment: the app reports a 500 error even though the debugger shows it executing that line fine.

Comment: @AndrewLindzon No that cannot be a reason, you are doing something wrong

Comment: I know what is going wrong, just don't know how to fix it.  The return throws off an error the-result-of-a-query-cannot-be-enumerated-more-than-once if I try and use the results before executing the return.  So I appear to have a choice of returning the values or using them, but not both.  Anyone know a workaround.  I need to use the values returned by stored procedure, then pass them along to the application.

Comment: I found a solution. Since I only need to return One object, and not series of objects, i modified the stored procedure to use var r1 = r.ToList().First(); ... return r1; and removed

so it now returns one instance of the result not an IEnumerable of the results

In the app that calls the API I dropped [0] changing data[0].value to data.value